# dotnet core Controller ERROR return types

Tags: controller, .net-core, task

All the examples I can find of writing MVC API dotnet core controllers, the return values from Task (or async Task) are

```
return OK(result);
```

Where can I find other ones.  There had to be something like BadRequest, NotFound, or the like.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what exactly your problem? `OK` method is defined in [ControllerBase class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-2.0) that has also methods like [BadRequest()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-2.0), [NotFound()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_NotFound) etc

Comment: THAT's Exactly what I was looking for.  If you want to make it THE answer, I will check it.  Easy answer if you know where to look.  Thanks very much.

Comment: [Yogi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5280626/yogi-bear) that's cool, have added

Answer (score 0):

`OK()` method is defined in [ControllerBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-2.0) class that has also methods like [BadRequest()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-2.0), [NotFound()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_NotFound) etc..

Moreovere, if you check [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs) for those methods, you will find that by default they just create an appropriate instance of `IHttpActionResult`:

```
public virtual BadRequestResult BadRequest()
        => new BadRequestResult();
...

public virtual NotFoundResult NotFound()
        => new NotFoundResult();
```

and all available classes like [BadRequestResult](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Results/BadRequestResult.cs), [NotFoundResult](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Results/NotFoundResult.cs) you may check [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/tree/master/src/System.Web.Http/Results).

---

And documentation info about action results [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results).